# How do you expand a virtual drive using VMware Infrastructure Web Access?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, vmware-server

I have a VM on a linux box that needs to have it's drive expanded. The guest OS is XP. What steps do I need to take to expand the hard drive for the XP VM? I have access to the web management and can also ssh to the linux box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can ssh in to the the host, you can use [vmkfstools](http://www.jume.nl/esx4man/man1/vmkfstools.1.html)

The command would look something like this

```
    vmkfstools –X 20000M
```

Where the size is the desired total size of the disk.

Comment: After I increase the site of the drive and boot back up the VM would XP automatically see the new space?

Comment: You might have to go into administration tools and resize your partition.

Comment: It's the only drive for that VM (the XP boot partition). I would think that XP might not boot up. I don't have as much experience on linux vmware so I want to make sure I go about this correctly. Thanks for your help.